# UITableView height when rotating to landscape

Tags: iphone

I'am trying to change the height of a `UITableView` when rotating to landscape (in the `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method), but the change didn't take effect.

It takes an effect when I changed the size in the `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` method, but it shouldn't be there !

The user will notice the change if I do it after the rotation finished.

Is there any other way to do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check your autoresizing masks?
If you set the properly, it will scale the table view for you automatically. If you have autoresizing masks enabled and you're changing the frame it might mess things up since it's scaling it automatically too.
Try setting it to:

```
UIViewAutoresizingNone
```

Comment: I set the mask to UIViewAutoresizingNone, and it works perfectly .. thanks